# Difference between binding control and accessor control in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

While attempting to write my own custom form control, I came up with different ways to implement it: using accessor or just simple binding (see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k7nien)

Basically the accessor custom control:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'accessor',
  template: `
    <input #input
           (input)="onChange($event.target.value)"
           (blur)="onTouched()"
    />
  `,
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: AccessorComponent,
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class AccessorComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @ViewChild('input') input;
  onChange;
  onTouched;

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  writeValue(value) {
    this.input.nativeElement.value = value;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled) {
    this.input.nativeElement.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

}
```

and the binding custom control:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'binding',
  template: `
    <input [value]="control.value"
           [disabled]="control.disabled"
           (input)="control.markAsDirty(); control.setValue($event.target.value)"
           (blur)="control.markAsTouched()"
    />
  `
})
export class BindingComponent {
  @Input() control;
}
```

I wonder the differences between them. In particular am I still writing async code in the binding custom control? While the accessor custom control is sync? And when to use one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

Binding is used into HTML as declarative programataion while accesor method is used by other objects.

Declarative
HTML
    
COMPONENT

```
class BindClass {
    @Input() bind : any;
}
```

Used by other object under POO paradigm

COMPONENT

```
@Component({selector:'bind', ...})
class BindClass implements OnInit {
   @Input() bind: any

    ngOnInit() {
       this.bind.name = 'name';
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<bind [bind]="othercomponent"></bind>
```

OTHER COMPONENT

```
@Component({selector: 'othercomponent', ...})
export class OtherComponent {
    private _name: string;
    set name(name:string) {
        this._name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, not too sure if your answer did address my questions, may be its just my understanding, could you please directly answer my questions about async and sync?